# I loaded my database using automapper. Now how do I get the data back out and into the viewModel again?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

So I have a 7 ViewModels that reference 3 domain models, I used automapper to map the Models to the ViewModels,  That worked great, now I want to populate the ViewModel from data stored in the database and I'm running into alot of problems.

Here is my Automapper.Configure()

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    //Configure dynamically at save time.
    CreateMap<Step0ViewModel,Preparer>();
    CreateMap<Step1ViewModel, BusinessInformation>();
    CreateMap<Step2ViewModel, dr405>();
    CreateMap<Step3ViewModel, dr405>();
    CreateMap<Step4ViewModel, dr405>();
    CreateMap<Step5ViewModel, dr405>();
    CreateMap<Step6ViewModel, dr405>();
}
```

How do I tell the application, "When I load from DBContext, move the entity into the ViewModel automatically", It seems like with Automapper you can load an entity from a ViewModel, but not the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper can do the reverse, you just have to create the map for it:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    //Configure dynamically at save time.
    CreateMap<Preparer, Step0ViewModel>();
    ...
}
```

As for loading mapping automatically at load time, I'm not aware of this functionality but it can be setup with a mapping helper to your linq query pretty easy:

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static TResult MapTo<TResult>(this object self)
    {
        if (self == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        return (TResult)Mapper.Map(self, self.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
    }
}
```

Then in your query:

```
var viewModel = _myContext.Preparers.Find(1).MapTo<Step0ViewModel>();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I pasted up the whole extension class if you want: http://pastebin.com/QFB6YE0i  There's a bit of wonkiness in the mapping to an existing object (since they're reference types the passed parameter gets modified too).

Answer (score 2):

AutoMapper doesn't automatically define bi-directional mappings. If you want to map from your view model to the corresponding domain model you should define this mapping as well:

```
CreateMap<Step0ViewModel, Preparer>();
CreateMap<Preparer, Step0ViewModel>();
```

Comment: Is this right to do?  Jim Bogard seemed to have an article condeming this, but I may not have understood the article.

Comment: @Doug, He did condemn it, but that's really only a philosophical view, imo. He didn't explicitly prevent bi-directional mapping because some people can and will put it to good use.

Comment: @Doug I believe in AutoMapper 2 Jim Bogard has come around and is looking more at expanding bi-directional mapping - better support for unflattening.  At least that's what I've gathered from various comments here and there - can't find sources now unfortunately.  Not much word on when that might be though.  Currently you can use CreateMap<T1, T2>().ForMember(d => d.Prop1, o => o.MapFrom(...)) to do inflation.